# How to display a UserControl object in a ListBox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a .Net Framework [`ListBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) and add two items, but one is shown only.

The code:

```
private class VisibleObject
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "VisibleObject";
    }
}

private class InvisibleObject : UserControl
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "InvisibleObject";
    }
}

private void InsertItems()
{
    listbox.Items.Add(new VisibleObject());
    listbox.Items.Add(new InvisibleObject());
}
```

With this code, the `VisibleObject` is shown in the Listbox, but the `InvisibleObject` not. The `InvisibleObject` based on `UserControl`.

The Listbox should show the result of `ToString()`, but this does not work with a `UserControl`. Why and how can I show a `UserControl` inside a `ListBox`?

Comment: Not sure if this helps, I got it to work with `private class InvisibleObject : Object`

Comment: @NickAbbot: No, I want to add `UserControl` items to the ListBox`.

Comment: Yeah, I get it - doesn't work. Your override, `return "InvisibleObject";`, doesn't even fire off. I even tried creating a custom usercontrol. It's adds it, but it's just a blank space

Comment: I don't think you're going to be able to do that. A DataGridView could do it for you but you're limited to what controls you can add.

Comment: Consider using a FlowLayoutPanel instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to do it using the [`ListControl.Format`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.format) event:

```
listbox.Format += listbox_Format;

private void listbox_Format(object sender, ListControlConvertEventArgs e)
{
    e.Value = e.ListItem.ToString();
}
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly declare that the object can be converted to string, decorating the class with a [TypeConverterAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.typeconverterattribute).

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(StringConverter))]
private class InvisibleObject : UserControl {
    public override string ToString() {
        return "InvisibleObject";
    }
}
```

Then, when you add the UserControl to the ListBox:

```
// [...]
listbox.Items.Add(new InvisibleObject());
```

its `ToString()` method is going to be called.